# Jboss access a resource under WEB-INF in web.xml

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, jboss, web.xml

My web.xml uses a form based authentication. The form error page resides under 
`WEB-INF/folder1/folder2/error.gsp` inside the project war.

The problem is the web.xml is unable to access the resource. It says the file is not found.

```
    <login-config>
       <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
       <realm-name>login</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.html</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/WEB-INF/folder1/folder2/error.gsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

I tried using different paths for `form-error-page` , but still the error wont go away. I tried moving it out of WEB-INF, where it works. But I want it inside WEB-INF, as it needs to access other resources.

Comment: Perhaps try /folder1/folder2/error.gsp as the web.xml is usually located in the /WEB-INF/ folder?

Comment: jimfromsa is right.
Just using /folder1/folder2/error.gsp
So, in your case, folder1 is the same path of login.html